# split dynamic comma delimetred data into pairs using vba to use in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

just need to highlight with yellow colour the textrange in PPT for all slides.
got the highlightable texts and starting positions in a comma delimetered variant variable.
from that variable need to split into pairs to help further code on highlighting by yellow.

> example variable RetRes may have £,130,€,63,$,16,
>   from this need RetRes should turns into [(£,130)(€,63)($,16)]

[(text1,position1)(text2,position2)(text3,position3)]

```
            substr = Split(RetRes, ",")
            For i = LBound(substr) To UBound(substr)
                substr(i) = Trim(substr(i))
                msgbox " SubStr: " & substr(i)
            Next i
```

by the above code couldn't use as expected. Please help to use the pairs as below

```
           shp6.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Restres(j), len(Restres)).select
```

where as Restres(j) should have position1 for text1.

Comment: any improvisation will help me; need a loop handling

Answer (score 0):

```
    Function RegExSample(testString As String, oSource As TextRange)
             Dim oReg2 As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp           
             Set oReg2 = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
             With oReg2
              .Global = True
              .Multiline = False
              .ignorecase = True
              .pattern = "([$€£])([ ])+(?=\d)" 'Checks for currencies with one or more following space(s)
              End With
                            
            If oReg2.test(testString) Then oSource.text = oReg2.Replace(testString, "<name>$1$2</name>")
    End Function
    Sub makeHighlight()
      'checks for the tags. When it finds them, it highlighted
      'or italics the text.
       Dim oSld As Slide
       Dim oShp As Shape
       Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
       Dim openTag As TextRange
       Dim closeTag As TextRange
       Dim endRange As Long
       Dim startRange As Long
                            
       For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
          ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=oSld.SlideIndex
              For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
                  If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
                  Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                  Set openTag = oTxtRng.Find(findwhat:="<name>", _
                                            MatchCase:=False)
                        Do While Not (openTag Is Nothing)
                                            Set closeTag = oTxtRng.Find(findwhat:="</name>", _
                                                MatchCase:=False)
                             If closeTag Is Nothing Then
                                                endRange = oTxtRng.Length
                             Else
                                                endRange = closeTag.Start - 1
                                                oTxtRng.Characters(closeTag.Start, _
                                                    closeTag.Length).Delete
                              End If
                                            startRange = openTag.Start
                            
                                            oTxtRng.Characters(startRange, _
                                            endRange - startRange + 1) _
                                            .Select
                                            ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2.Font.Highlight.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 175)
                                            
                                            oTxtRng.Characters(openTag.Start, _
                                                openTag.Length).Delete
                                            Set openTag = oTxtRng.Find(findwhat:="<name>", _
                                                MatchCase:=False)
                                        Loop
                            
                                    End If
                                Next oShp
                            Next oSld
                            For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
                                For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
                                    If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
                                        Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                                        Set openTag = oTxtRng.Find(findwhat:="<name>", _
                                            MatchCase:=False)
                                        Do While Not (openTag Is Nothing)
                                            Set closeTag = oTxtRng.Find(findwhat:="</name>", _
                                                MatchCase:=False)
                                            If closeTag Is Nothing Then
                                                endRange = oTxtRng.Length
                                            Else
                                                endRange = closeTag.Start - 1
                                                oTxtRng.Characters(closeTag.Start, _
                                                    closeTag.Length).Delete
                                            End If
                                            startRange = openTag.Start
                                            oTxtRng.Characters(startRange, _
                                                endRange - startRange + 1) _
                                                .Font.Italic = True
                                            oTxtRng.Characters(openTag.Start, _
                                                openTag.Length).Delete
                                            Set openTag = oTxtRng.Find(findwhat:="<name>", _
                                                MatchCase:=False)
                                        Loop
                            
                                    End If
                                Next oShp
                            Next oSld
    End Sub
    Sub HighlightCurrencieswithSpaces()
        Dim sld As Slide
        Dim shp2 As Shape
        Dim shpText2 As TextRange
            For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
                For Each shp2 In sld.Shapes
                     If shp2.HasTextFrame Then
                        Set shpText2 = shp2.TextFrame.TextRange
                        RegExSample shpText2.text, shpText2
                     End If
                Next shp2
             Next sld
       Call makeHighlight
    End Sub
```

Though I have the solution with above compilation, having a small issue with this as follows
spaces between currencies are not retaining as it is; for example, if there were 5 spaces between currency symbol and numbers, after running the code, its having only one space between currency symbol and numbers and getting highlighted those symbol with single space.

> [**$** 500,00.255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqgUG.png)

NEED: should highlight with all existing spaces between symbol and number

> [**$**      500,00.255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k16M.png)

your contribution will be a very grateful-thanking you.

Comment: I achieved my requirement. Thanks for support